# Android onFocusChanged function never called

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom button in extending `View` class as specified in this tutorial:

> http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/09/13/making-a-custom-android-button-using-a-custom-view/

But I have a problem with the function `onFocusChanged()` which is never called.

This is my code:

```
public class CustomButton extends View
{
    ...
    public CustomButton(Context context, Car car) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setOnClickListener(listenerAdapter);
        setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction,
                                  Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
    {
        if (gainFocus == true)
        {
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In fact, when I click on my custom button nothing happens... With the debugger, I can see that the function is never called. And I don't know why.

So, had I forgotten a step ? Is there another thing I have missed ?

Comment: The focus event isn't related to the click event. If you want to do something when you click the button, then add a onclick listener.

Answer (score 9):

In fact, the problem was that I haven't set the property "focusable in touch mode" of my custom button to true. I have added in the constructor `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` and it works better. Thank you Phil and Vicki D for your help.

```
public class CustomButton extends View
{
    ...
    public CustomButton(Context context, Car car) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // Needed to call onFocusChanged()
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setOnClickListener(listenerAdapter);
        setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction,
                                  Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
    {
        if (gainFocus == true)
        {
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);  
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say "When overriding, be sure to call up through to the super class so that the standard focus handling will occur." You've omitted that call in your code above, something like below should help.

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
{

    if (gainFocus == true)
    {
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);  
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it's still not working. With the debugger the function is never called. I have also tried to put the call to the super class before my treatment but it does the same thing.

Comment: What kind of container is your custom button in?

Comment: My custom button is in a LinearLayout contained in another LinearLayout.

Comment: Is there another control in there that may be capturing the onFocusChanged event instead?

Comment: In the first LinearLayout, I have a LinearLayout containing my custom button, and a FrameLayout containing a Button. I will try with deleting the button.

Comment: So I have tried to delete the button which is in the FrameLayout but it's still not working... The function onFocusChanged() is not called.

Comment: Try putting the call to super.onFocusChanged() before the rest of the code in your method

Comment: In fact, the problem was that I haven't set the property "focusable in touch mode" of my custom button to true. I have added in the constructor `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` and it works better. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you must `setOnFocusChangeListener`in your constructor. something like this:

```
 public CustomButton(Context context, Car car) 
{
    ...
    setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    ...
}
```